# What affects when Chrome begins to spell check a word?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocorrect

I'm trying to fix a bug with our current code, here is the issue.
On one text input, when you begin typing, Chrome will not red underline the word until you press space.

But in another field, Chrome will automatically start highlighting the word in red as you type.

The goal is to have the latter field behave like the former (only highlight when the user has finished typing the word).

I'm trying to figure out what causes the difference between them. Code wise, they're both

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>` with some other properties that I don't think will make a difference (one has a name, one has a name and an id).

(I've also done this on the same version of chrome, so I don't think that's the issue)
Am I missing something obvious here?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't tell if it's the case in your code, I encountered the same thing, and the answer was that Chrome spellchecks the current word whenever a script sets `document.title`, even to its current value. A mitigation is to manually de-dupe `document.title` changes like so:

```
function setDocumentTitle(value) {
  if (document.title !== value) {
    document.title = value;
  }
}
```

Reproduction: https://jsfiddle.net/twhb/6z89pnrq/

Bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=772856

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue. I tried commenting out every call to `document.title` in our code, but the issue persists.

Comment: @Kolichikov I read that some other DOM modifications trigger it too. I would try removing all JS, then enabling it piece by piece until the issue shows up. Also, FYI, the issue is apparently fixed in the upcoming version of Chrome.